# GASでスプレッドシートからGmailでの下書きメールを自動作成する際に、bodyを2つ挿入したい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートからGASを用いてGmailの下書きを自動作成しています。

**A**のようなシートから、**B**のようなメールを作成したいのですが
セルの異なる本文①と本文②を画像のようにbody内に一緒に記載させる方法がわかりません。

**A**
[image: 元スプレッドシート]

↓

**B**
[image: 欲しい発現]

現在のスクリプトは以下のとおりです。
data[6]
をどのように入れればいいのかがわかりません。

```
function allsend() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow()-2;
  var columns = sheet.getLastColumn()-2;
  
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,3,rows,columns);
  var datas = range.getValues();
  
  datas.forEach(function(data){
    
  var category = data[0];
  var recipient = data[1];
  var cc = data[2];
  var bcc = data[3];
    
  var subject = data[4];
  var body = data[5];
    
  var options = {
    cc:cc,
    bcc:bcc,
  }
  
  if(category == true){  //チェックされている場合のみメール作成
  GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options);
  }
  });
}
```

お力添えいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 中身はダミーで構わないので、実際のスプレッドシートのサンプルや、具体的にどんな結果を求めているのかを質問に含めた方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
一度自分の中で整理して、出直します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

表示されているスプレッドシートとサンプルメールから、使用したい列は、次のように理解しました。

- Category: Column "C"
- Recipient: Column "D"
- cc: Column "E"
- bcc: Column "F"
- Subject: Column "G"
- Body: Column "H", "I"

これを使用してスクリプトを修正すると、次のような修正はいかがでしょうか。

#### 修正したスクリプト

```js
function allsend() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("A3:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values.forEach(([, , category, recipient, cc, bcc, subject, ...body]) => {
    if (category === true) {
      GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body.join("\n"), { cc, bcc });
    }
  });
}
```

- スプレッドシートの画像から2行のヘッダ行を確認しましたので、ヘッダ行を除外してデータを取得し、そのデータから列Cのチェックボックスがチェックされている行に対して値を取得してドラフトメールを作成する流れです。

Comment: やりたいことが完璧にできました。
しかも短くなって、素敵です。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @Shin Melodist ご返事、並びに動作テストをしていただきありがとうございます。無事解決したとのことで安心しました。